# How can I create epoch from String?

Tags: javascript, datetime, epoch

All, I need to create epoch time from a string using Javascript.  Now I know that I can use the following:

```
var dateStr = '01/01/2016 1:10 PM'
var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(dateObj.getSeconds());
```

The problem I have is that using the above code my data has the millisecond in it.  Take the following as an example:

```
var dateStr = '01/01/2016 1:10:49.181 PM'
var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(dateObj.getSeconds());
```

Using that format, I get a NaN error.  Is there a way to convert the date time in the second example to epoch while retaining the milliseconds?

Comment: You forgot to ut `()` after `getSeconds` to call the function. And it doesn't return milliseconds, it just returns `0` because there are no seconds in your time.

Comment: I think you're talking about `getTime()`, not `getSeconds()`. Divide the milliseconds by 1000 to get seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a possible workaround:

```
var dateStr = '01/01/2016 1:10:49.181 PM',
    reg = new RegExp(/\.[0-9]{1,3}/);

var dateObj = new Date(dateStr.replace(reg, ''));

console.log(
  (dateObj.getTime() + 1000 * Number(reg.exec(dateStr)[0]))
);
```

This will include the milliseconds in the final result (1451650249181). You may also discard them entirely, in which case you only need the *replace* part without the *exec* part.

**Reverse operation**

Below is a possible approach for the reverse operation, using the standard Date methods.

*Beware: barely tested.*

```
var ts = new Date(1451650249181);

var dateStr =
  ('0' + ts.getDate()).substr(-2, 2) + '/' +
  ('0' + (ts.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2, 2) + '/' +
  ts.getFullYear() + ' ' +
  (ts.getHours() % 12 || 12) + ':' +
  ('0' + ts.getMinutes()).substr(-2, 2) + ':' +
  ('0' + ts.getSeconds()).substr(-2, 2) + '.' +
  ('00' + (ts.getTime() % 1000)).substr(-3, 3) + ' ' +
  (ts.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM');
```

Comment: You're the man, thank you.  I'm going to need to do the reverse here soon.  Do you know of a cross platform workaround that will allow be to include milliseconds into my date object?  Again, this will be headless using rhino.

Comment: @user316114 Well. Off the top of my head, I can't think of an easy _and elegant_ cross platform workaround for the reverse operation. See my edited answer for a possible solution, but it's a rather bloated piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

`dateObj.getTime()` will return milliseconds since the epoch. Divide it by 1000 and round to get seconds.

```js
var dateStr = '01/01/2016 1:10 PM'
var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(Math.round(dateObj.getTime() / 1000));

var dateStr = '01/01/2016 1:10:49.181'
var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(Math.round(dateObj.getTime() / 1000));
```

Comment: Yes, this works for '01/01/2016 1:10 PM', I'm trying to do this for the following value: '01/01/2016 1:10:49.181'

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. But date parsing is implementation-specific. You might want to use `moment.js` if you need more control.

Comment: I plugged this right into a sandbox project, pure html and javascript and for the second (with milliseconds) I'm getting NaN.  This appears to be browser specific.  Your code works on Chrome but not Safari.  In my application i'm running this javascript headless using Rhino, any suggestions other than using moment.js?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) shows the standard date formats that Javascript can parse, and they don't include fractions of a second. So if you don't want to use moment.js, you'll need to write your own code that looks for the decimal and removes it, e.g. `date.replace(/\.\d+/, '')`